# Steps to take to take to safely share my little server with classmates

Tags: permissions, security, users, file-sharing

My school recently gave every student a Chromebook. They are obviously pretty locked down and limited but they do support SSH. Some of my friends and I are interested in programming and I thought that it would be fun for all of us to have an account on my little Ubuntu box (a converted Windows Vista computer from ~2007) just for experimenting and testing purposes so that they could all have a chance play around in Python, C++, administer a Minecraft server, bypass the Chromebook filter, etc.

I generally trust the guys, and the computer isn't critical to any of our day-to-day activities, but I was wondering if there were any specific security considerations I should take before letting them set up accounts. If one of them was to make some rogue program, how could I make sure it doesn't delete any of the files on my account?

Comment: Permissions are important: more -> https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give `sudo`/`root` access.  Whatever servers you create, ensure that the server is running by it's own access in it's own space.  For instance if you were running a web server, it would be running as the user `www-data`.  `www-data` can make changes in its area but can't make any changes outside of it's access control.

So check the name of the `userid` and `groupid` of the running server to verify that it's running in it's own space.

Most servers will already come with this design.

Also, you yourself might consider being careful when running elevated `sudo` commands.  It'll take an elevated command to make system-wide changes.  So if as you are concerned one of your `guru` students wanted to try to gain control of your server, they might try to get you to run a script or a problem that would turn on elevated access to him or one of his programs.  If you ran the test programs as a normal user, you couldn't make inadvertent harmful changes.

Only run `sudo` commands when you are intentionally aware of specifics that you want to install or configure.

**Your Personal Space**

By default your home directory is browser and readable by the world.  You in the permission command it's the `O` for others.  The `x` on a directory is permission to enter it.  The `r` on a directory or file means permission to read the content.

Your home folder looks something like this if you haven't changed it:
*(The output of `ls ~/` which is your home directory)*

```
$ ls -l ~/
drwxr-xr-x 24 apollo apollo 4096 Sep 25 18:03 apollo
```

In this case `apollo` is the userid groupid.  The permissions are in groups of three, `uuugggooo`.  The first three is you the user.  The second three is the group permission, and the last three is others or everybody.

The permission bits are:

```
r - Read
w - write
x - execute (or for a directory enter)
```

So if you look at the default permission above you can see that everyone can read and enter the directory.  This can be changed with the command `chown`.  For instance:

```
$ chmod go-rx ~/
```

That command would make the specific directory inaccessible to the groups and others.  The home folder would then look like this:

```
drwxr----- 24 apollo apollo 4096 Sep 25 18:03 apollo
```

Having that type of permission, no one can browse your personal space.  Of course if it were something you wanted to share, you could perform that command on your `~/Documents` folder or any other folder that you want to be sure no one can browse.

While by default many of your folders can be browsed, they can't be changed by others.

You might consider making a test account for yourself and using it to test what is available to the students.

You most likely have good students, but most children as well as most people, will be curious and try to go to a place where they might feel is off limit out of curiosity.  Also, your student, while they shouldn't could likely share the password with the friends and brothers who might be more inquisitive.

Comment: Good advice.. :-)

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks, I tried not to write a novel, but wanted to get the OP something to consider as a point of reference for their research.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll see where I can go from here!